# MSB4236 The SDK Microsoft.NET.Sdk specified could not be found

Tags: c++, .net, sdk

I've created a CLR (.NET Core) project and added a Windows Form there. I didn't change any code and tried to run the program. Then the error MSB4236 The SDK Microsoft.NET.Sdk specified could not be found comes in.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Z3k.png)

The header file code:

```
`#pragma once

namespace Project21 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

protected:
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

private:
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container();
        this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(300,300);
        this->Text = L"MyForm";
        this->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(0);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
    }
 #pragma endregion
};
} `
```

Answer (score 0):

My error message was

> C:\code\SomeSolution\tests\MyProject.Tests.Unit\MyProject.Tests.Unit.csproj : error : C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.
> C:\code\SomeSolution\tests\MyProject.Tests.Unit\MyProject.Tests.Unit.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

After looking at [MSB4236: The SDK 'name' specified could not be found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/msbuild/errors/msb4236?view=vs-2017) and examining MyProject.Tests.Unit.csproj, I looked at folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400` and noticed that it only had a few folders in it unlike sibling folders `6.0.407` and `7.0.202` which each had many folders in them.

**SOLUTION (TL;DR)**

I deleted folder `6.0.400` from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\` .

That's it!  The build worked after deleting that folder.  It was just a guess that deleting that folder would keep MSBuild from trying to use that version of the .NET SDK.

Disclaimer: Your mileage may vary. Other things can cause a MSB4236 error.